# why is the groovy gradle problem occur when i pull the project from github?

Tags: android-studio

when I make new flutter project at my computer every thing is fine.
But when I connect github repository and pull the project and build, these error occur
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buq0f.png)
And also I don't see anything in the Android app unit, only 'nothing to show' message is appear. how can i solve it..?

I do dart sdk update, and redownload flutter package. i want to solve my problem clearly...

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.